# import through phpmyadmin

Tags: php, csv, phpmyadmin

How do i import a csv file to phpmyadmin.
In one column1\2\3.It should go with out escaping \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in php you could do this.

this should convert the csv file into an array

```
$csvhead = array();
$leads = array();

if(($handle = fopen("file.csv","r"))!==FALSE){
  while(($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,","))!==FALSE){
    $lead = array();
        if($row==1){
         $csvhead = $data;
        } else {
          foreach($csvhead as $heading) {
              $lead[$heading] = $data[array_search($heading,$csvhead)];
          }
          $leads[] = $lead;
        }

        $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

then access the array like this

```
foreach($leads as $lead){
    echo $lead["header name"];
}
```

Comment: yes i read the question right, but he's using php right as he's got phpmyadmin ;)

Comment: i tried a similar solution with phpmyadmin on localhost and then on a remote host. csv importing can be disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Without screen shots....hard...go into phpmyadmin, look for the import tab (top) and start play with it until you get it right.
Any way, this does not belong here, and I am pretty sure this can easily be figured out by experimenting.

Comment: Hint: Format of imported file ;)

Comment: @answerGot the solution: just put \ and \ by selecting csv